# How to override controller in PrestaShop 1.5.x from a theme?

Tags: php, overriding, smarty, prestashop

I want to override modules\blockwishlist\controllers\front\mywishlist.php

and more specifically

```
{
    $this->display_column_left = false; (to be true)
    parent::initContent();

    $this->assign();
}
```

However i need to make it in a theme, so when users install the theme they don't need to place override file anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override module controller in PrestaShop 1.5

Workaround: Clone the module with different name and do the necessary changes. When you're ready with the theme export it via the "Import/export a theme" module and pick that module from the "Modules" block ("Select the modules that you wish to export"). This way that module will be packaged along with the theme and will be installed when the theme is installed.

Note that that module is creating 4 tables during the installation and dropping them when unistalled.